# Unity command line to open a project with compilation errors and immediately close it

Tags: unity-game-engine, command-line

I am looking for a command line that would open a Unity project in batchmode, nographics, ignore all compilations errors, and close the project immediately after it opens.

I already have :

```
Unity -batchmode -nographics -quit -ignorecompilationerrors -projectPath MyProject
```

but it hangs out and never close. I had to kill the process at some point, however I think it worked because the specific effect I was looking for was present the second time I opened the project

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't just importing things? Did you start with an intact Library directory? You can tail the editor.log file or have it log to stdout to see what's happening.

Comment: You could use `-executeMethod` to execute a function that calls `EditorApplication.Exit`and see if that helps. Pretty sure the editor just exits anyway when whatever function you called ends.

Comment: What exactly is it you are wanting to achieve with that? And `quit` already would make sure that unity exits as soon as everything is finished so I would actually join @RetiredNinja and suspect things have still been importing  .. probably finished the import then when you open the second time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to post the solution

The project was indeed stuck while importing, this was due to the "parallel import" checkbox being selected.

It worked ok on Windows but not on Macos, even if on that platform, it didn't prevent to open the project and build from it, you simply had to open it twice to get rid of the errors.

Unchecking the checkbox made the build function properly

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted in comments, it might be that your project was still importing. You can use the `-logfile` flag to keep track of the importing process (as per the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditorCommandLineArguments.html)):

> `-logfile`: Specify where Unity writes the Editor or Windows/Linux/OSX standalone log file. To output to the console, specify - for the path name. On Windows, use -logfile -  to direct the output to stdout, which by default is not the console.

If you feel like the import is taking too long, you can also try activating [Parrallel Import](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ParallelImport.html):

> Edit > Project Settings > Editor, then under the Asset Pipeline section, enable the Parallel Import checkbox.

This will utilize multiple threads when running the project import, and should significantly speed up import times.